# codeigniter project database upgrade scripts

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm looking for ideas to properly handle my project's mysql table updates across environments. I've taken a look at the `CI DB Forge` class and I believe this *might* help me out a bit. My thoughts are to:

1. create a new file for each database install, table upgrade or change. The file would contain the raw mysql query to do each relevant task
2. run the upgrade scripts via hooks before any controllers are loaded
3. continue loading the project

Is this the correct thinking? This is pretty similar to how Magento handles database upgrades per extensions.

Comment: If you're disciplined enough to write out the SQL for each change, great.  If you have multiple environments, though (more than 2), even that might not be enough.  I've been using the mysql workbench db comparison tools lately to migrate database changes; it works reasonably well.

Comment: I am using dev, testing and production environments. The database changes are simple in nature and I've been handling them by just copy/pasting through Navicat currently. I am just looking for a more **professional** means to handle it. Does the workbench tool actually produce the sql query to patch upgrades?

Comment: I've just learned that Navicat has Data & Structure Compare and Sync tools built into the version I have which is great, but I'd still love a programmatic solution.

Comment: There's also a mysql command line utility to diff databases and generate the SQL to merge them: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcompare.html  I wouldn't consider it safe to run the sql changes autmatically on a production server, though - certain structural changes can break your site; it's better to manually look through the changes you're about to apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the [Migrations class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html). This is a fairly new library, and the documentation at this moment is not too good in my opinion.

If you enable this library in `application/config/migrations.php` and load it, the it will create a database table called `migrations`. The workflow from there is the following:

1. Create a new file under `application/migrations` make sure you name it with sequentially numbered file name like `001_some_descriptive_name.php`. The format is important, **exactly 3 numbers** and at least one `_` after them.
2. In the new file create a class named after the file name, so the `001_some_descriptive_name.php` should hold a class called `Migration_Some_descriptive_name` and extend the `CI_Migration` class. The class name casing is important, first `Migration_` then **one uppercase** letter then lowercase.
3. Create a public `up` and a public `down` method inside the class
4. Inside the up method add your migration code, that changes the database. You can use the db forge library or just plain old `$this->db->query()` calls. Dbforge is more portable if you need to support multiple database systems its probably better to use that.
5. Inside the `down` method add the code that would reverse the effects of `up`. If `up` adds a column then `down` should drop that column, if `up` creates a table, `down` should drop that table and so on.
6. Once you finished your migration class bump the `migration_version` inside the migration config file.
7. Create a controller load the migration library and call `$this->migration->current()` this will check the version from the `migration` database table and run the migration classes `up` or `down` methods in order to reach the migration version in the config file you set at step 6. So for example if the database says you are at version 2, and the config says you should be on 5, then it will run the `up` method of the migrations with `003_...`, `004_...`, `005_..` filenames in order. If you set lower number then the current the `down` methods will be called. The database starts the counting from 0 so don't create a `000_...` file.

If you feel adventurous you can create a hook that loads the migration class and runs the `get_instance()->migration->latest()` on every page load so every environment will auto update the db once you deploy a new migration class.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed! Not sure how I missed it but I'm going to give this a go. Thanks for the very detailed and helpful write-up...Have you used this yourself in any projects?

Comment: Is `Migration_Some_descriptive_name` the right class name? It doesn't contain a number. In the file that's the most important part...

Comment: @Rudie, yes the class names don't need numbers in front of them only the file names (this for the ordering). It would be parse error to start a class, function or even a variable name with number.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on this. I just successfully added all my upgrade scripts to my project and have them running with a `post_controller_constructor` hook. Now I just have to remember to add my scripts faithfully :)